# Scheduling software with Google 2-way sync, redirect URL, limited availablity

Tags: calendar, time-management, synchronization, scheduling, saas

I run a business that requires me to enable people throughout the USA to be able to schedule phone appointments with me.

I'm having a lot of trouble finding a service that helps manage my calendar.

I've looked at ScheduleOnce, Calendly, 10to8, YouCanBookMe, TimeTrade, AcuityScheduling, Square Appointments, Bookly Plugin... and more... including open source PHP projects that I'd host on my own server.

None of them are as good as I expected, and I didn't even think my requirements were all that greedy.

What I want is:

1. A basic **public booking page that lets the person view times in her own time zone** and see the available slots for the next 1-3 weeks.
2. **I want to ONLY offer these appointment slots** (60 mins each with 30 mins after-padding):

   - 9:15 AM
   - 10:45 AM
   - 12:45 PM
   - 2:15 PM
   - 3:45 PM
   - 5:15 PM
   - 6:45 PM
3. I want there to be a **2-way sync with Google Calendar** (including every separate calendar within) so that if I have any conflicts for any of those slots, those slots become unavailable / invisible to the prospect.
4. **Customizable thank-you page with embedded video and "Click to add to your calendar" button**

   - Upon creating the appointment, I want the thank-you page to have a "Click to add to your calendar" button (so that the user can conveniently copy the details to her own calendar), and I want the rest of the page to be completely customizable (so that I can have whatever header and text I want and embed a video to provide further instructions).
   - Or, a suitable alternative would be if upon booking the user is immediately **redirected to a URL** of my choice with parameters in the URL that contain all of the relevant booking data (date, time, time zone, person's name, etc).

In addition to those 4 requirements, of course I also require unlimited super flexible email/SMS/voice reminders. My assumption is that Apptoto will work as I'm imagining, in which case I can bolt it on to a calendar system for $29/month.

Do you happen to know of any other calendar services I should try?

I really appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: Google Calendars has a PHP (and other languages) API you can use to assist you in your efforts.  You can create a web front end that only displays those times(and whatever else you want) on the web page, and then use the Calendar API to create an event on your calendar, by adding the users email address it would automatically appear on the users gmail calendar.(Assuming they have a gmail account.)  If they don't, it depends on what calendar software they use on how hard it is.  Non gmail users would still receive an email. I have extensive Google Calendar API experience.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php

Comment: Google has hangout for SMS and voice, and 99% of google stuff has API a programmer can interface with.

Answer (score 1):

The $48 plan at https://youcanbook.me/pricing/ actually seems to be doing what I'd asked for in my question above.

It was just *really* tricky to figure out and set up.

The main steps that I wish I'd known about:

1. Choose "display 5 minute slots", "minimum 90 minutes", "default 90 minute booking", "maximum 90 minutes", 0 padding, "on duty events" = "Available for Appointments" (See https://youcanbook.me/feature/onduty/)
2. In "Afterwards", choose "Go to a URL" and use `http://my_URL.com/?e_start={START-ISO-8601}&e_end={END-ISO-8601}&e_timezone={TIMEZONE-BOOKER}&e_person_name={NAME}&e_cancel_link={CANCEL-LINK}` using the https://youcanbook.me/feature/mailmerge/ feature.
3. In Basic > Calendars > Change, I didn't notice/know that *other people's calendars* (when shared with me) were appearing here.  And they need to be unchecked or else their events will block my availability.